# Problems with web.xml using tomcat server 8.0

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, servlets

I made a simple tomcat servlet, following exactly this [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6YPK9xunCk&index=5&list=PLE0F6C1917A427E96).

I created a class called XmlServlet, which handles simple GET and POST  requests.

Here is my class:

Package First:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class XmlServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String UserName = request.getParameter("UserName");
        String FullName = request.getParameter("FullName");

        System.out.println("hello u" + UserName);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String UserName = request.getParameter("UserName");
        String FullName = request.getParameter("FullName");
        String location = request.getParameter("location");
        String prof = request.getParameter("prof");
        out.println("hello u from dpost" + UserName + "u full name" + FullName
                + "address" + location);

    }

}
```

and the Servlet:

```
package First;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class SimpleServlet
 */
@WebServlet(description = "My First One", urlPatterns = { "/SimpleServletPath" })
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public SimpleServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    }

}
```

and my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <!--  
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>XmlServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>First.Xmlservlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>XmlServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/SimpleServletPath</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
-->
</web-app>



and i create simple html page to represent this 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="SimpleServletPath">

        user name<input name="UserName" /> full name<input name="FullName" />
        <br>
         Work <input type="radio" name="prof" value="developer">developer</input>
        <input type="radio" name="prof" value="IT">IT</input>
         <select name="location" multiple size=3 >
            <option value="here">here</option>
            <option value="home">home</option>
            <option value="school">school</option>
            <option value="football">football</option>
            <option value="chelsea">Chelsea</option>
        </select> 
        </br> 
        <input type="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I cant get any data from the HTML page. Everything seems to work fine,
but I get an error about web.xml. 
Can someone help check my servlet, class and web.xml and tell me where the problem lies?

Comment: I suppose you tried this without commenting the info about the servlet in the web.xml (<!--     -->)?

Comment: suppose with out it <!--> i forget to removed it and i put<!-->  in my code because the problem that i talk about  @CoqPwner

Comment: @Ascalonian the problem with web.xml that can't get any data with my html page

Answer (score 0):

So, when you're on the HTML page and you submit, it goes to the servlet and you get a blank page, right?  Ok, well that's because your servlet has literally nothing in its `doGet` method.  Notice your form `action` is `SimpleServletPath` not `XmlServlet`. But wait, it gets worse!  In your SimpleServlet java file you map the path to `SimpleServletPath` with annotations.  But then you also map a second servlet, the  `XmlServlet` to the same path (!) with web.xml .... So its a total mess. (Maybe you actually get an error page because of the double mapping.)

So, to solve this, map each servlet to its own URL not both to the same URL.  Then make sure that whichever servlet you actually submit to from your HTML form actually prints something to the response.   And it would also be a good idea to decide whether you want to map servlets to URLS with annotations or with web.xml rather than mixing the two approaches.

Comment: XmlServlet  is class not servlet so i have only one servelt and map this class to that url 
iam sorry i just beginner with java EE and servlets i do the same like that tutorial  @developerwjk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6YPK9xunCk&index=5&list=PLE0F6C1917A427E96

Comment: @AhmedMahrous If you think so, then you are really confused, since you don't map regular classes via web.xml, and also your java file says `public class XmlServlet extends HttpServlet`: why are you extending HttpServlet if its not a servlet?  Maybe you should consider taking a Java web applications class (or buy a book). Not everything can be learned by watching youtube videos.

Comment: i did the same like that tutorial so why it work with him and not me ?

Comment: @AhmedMahrous Videos are no way to learn how to code. It worked for him and not you because there's more to it than what he showed, obviously. Or you missed something.

Comment: i don't know i just make like him step by step i want to go with the tutorial and that problem face me now
what i can do for that

Comment: and can u recommended me some tutoirals  or book to begin with jave EE i will be thankful for that @developerwjk